# How to call ugettext from Django shell?

Tags: django, localization, gettext

I am working on a Django project which is localized and works fine in many languages. Now for a reason I need to call `ugettext` from its shell.

Here is what I did:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
u'fa-ir'
>>> from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
>>> print _("Schedule & Details")
Schedule & Details
```

As you see the phrase "Schedule & Details" did not print in Persian language.

Is it possible to translate a phrase and then print it inside Django shell?

Comment: I don't see any reason this wouldn't work. Does the Persian translation file include a value for 'Schedule & Details'? Does this same string translate as expected via the web?

Comment: @Chris ... Yes the same string is used inside the site header and there it is what it must be

Comment: It probably doesn't make any difference, but have you tried `u"Schedule & Details"`? Python 2 strings aren't Unicode by default (though these characters all appear to be ASCII, which should amount to the same thing).

Comment: @Chris ... Sorry, again the same string returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django's normal translation feature depends on [`django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware), but middleware runs as part of the request / response cycle. Since you are in an interactive shell and there is no request object the middleware can't do its job.

If you manually activate the language in your shell you should see translation behaving as expected:

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate, ugettext as _
>>>
>>> activate('fa-ir')
>>> print _("Schedule & Details")
```

Of course, instead of hard-coding `'fa-ir'` you could load it from `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` if you wish.